# Need Help Understanding While Loops Problem?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I got this question right. The Answer is 13. But I simply don't Understand the question at all. I've been trying to watch youtube videos but I can't seem to understand this. Could someone please help me?

What is the output after the following code segment is executed?

```
int x = 1;
int y = 0;
while (x < 10)
{
     y = 5;
     while (y > x)
     {
          y--;
     }
     x += y;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Answer:  13, But I need help understanding why.

Comment: Why don't you use an IDE with debugger an go through it step-by-steo? Alternatively, you grab a piece of paper and write down the variable states for each step...

Comment: "But I need help understanding why." This is the wrong framing. Instead: tell me what you think the answer should be instead, and why. Go through your reasoning in detail and try to tell me why the computer is wrong. Either you will identify exactly what you misunderstand, and you can ask a properly *specific* question; or you will fail, because the logic will necessarily guide you to the computer's answer. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

for easy understanding, you can add some println() in loops and get something like

```
1 5 (x, y=5)
1 4 (x, y--)
1 3 (x, y--)
1 2 (x, y--)
1 1 (x, y--)
2   (x+y)

2 5 (x, y=5)
2 4 (x, y--)
2 3 (x, y--)
2 2 (x, y--)
4   (x+y)

4 5 (x, y=5)
4 4 (x, y--)
8   (x+y)

8 5 (x, y=5)
13  (x+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when we dry run the code provided:

```
Two variables are initialized -> x = 1,y = 0
```

1st Iteration

```
Next we go inside a while loop which will only fail when x will become greater 
than or equal to 10, which is not the case now as x=1

Next we are initializing y = 5

    Now the inner while loop condition says that until y becomes less than or equal 
    to current x value it will get execute and decrease the y value.
    Walkthrough: y = 5,x = 1 condition=true
                 y = 4,x = 1 condition=true
                 y = 3,x = 1 condition=true
                 y = 2,x = 1 condition=true
                 y = 1,x = 1 condition=false (loop break)
             
Finally we are adding y value to x : (x= x + y) For current walkthrough x = 1 + 1 = 2
```

2nd Iteration

```
Now as x is still not greater than or equal to 10
We again go inside the loop and each time one iteration will decrease because every time y value is initialized by 5, so now inner loop will break at 
y=2,x=2 condition=false 
x = x +y = 2 + 2 = 4
```

3rd Iteration

```
Again as x<10 i.e. (4<10)
Inner loop will break at 
y = 4,x = 4 condition=false
x = x + y = 4 + 4 = 8
```

4th Iteration

```
Again as x<10 i.e. (8<10)
Inner loop will break at  
y = 5,x = 8 condition=false
x = x + y = 8 + 5 = 13
```

5th Iteration

```
Outer loop condition fails as now x>10 i.e. (13>10)
```

Finally x value is printed on the console i.e. 13

Answer (score -1):

[The code is shown above in the picture ,do trace this way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGXaE.jpg)

first y:5
second y:4
second y:3
second y:2
second y:1
third x:2
first y:5
second y:4
second y:3
second y:2
third x:4
first y:5
second y:4
third x:8
first y:5
third x:13
finall x:13

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as image, so that it can easily be copied / tested